# Code not executing in IAsyncEnumerable iterator, after lock in finally

Tags: c#, async-await, iasyncenumerable, linq-async

I am experiencing a strange issue while enumerating an [`IAsyncEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1), with the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) operator [`Take`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/Take.cs) attached to it. In my iterator I have a try-finally block with some values yielded inside the `try` block, and some clean-up code inside the `finally` block. The clean-up code is inside a `lock` block. The issue is that whatever code follows the `lock` block is not executed. No exception is thrown, the code is just ignored like it's not there. [Here is a program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/akfS1K) that reproduces this behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        await foreach (var item in GetStream().Take(1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {item}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Done");
    }

    static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetStream()
    {
        var locker = new object();
        await Task.Delay(100);
        try
        {
            yield return 1;
            yield return 2;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Finally before lock");
            lock (locker) { /* Clean up */ }
            Console.WriteLine($"Finally after lock");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```xml
Received: 1
Finally before lock
Done
```

The text *"Finally after lock"* is not printed in the console!

This only happens with the `Take` operator attached. Without the operator the text is printed as expected.

Is this a bug in the `System.Linq.Async` library, a bug in the C# compiler, or something else?

As a workaround I am currently using a nested try-finally block inside the `finally`, which works but it's awkward:

```
finally
{
    try
    {
        lock (locker) { /* Clean up */ }
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Finally after lock");
    }
}
```

.NET Core 3.1.3, .NET Framework 4.8.4150.0, C# 8, System.Linq.Async 4.1.1, Visual Studio 16.5.4, Console Application

Comment: Very interesting behavior. The code within the lock is executed; the same thing happens for `Take(2)`; for `Take(3)`, the `"Finally after lock"` is emitted.

Comment: You should report it at https://github.com/dotnet/reactive

Comment: Small question. Why do you need lock there?

Comment: @GuruStron because I add an object in a collection at the start of the enumeration, and remove it when the enumeration is finished. And using a `lock` is the simplest way to ensure thread safety.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I was a little bit confused cause lock object was local to the method in the repro =). Also it is up for debate but personally I would say using [concurrent collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netcore-3.1)  would be the simplest one)

Comment: @GuruStron yeap, the code I posted is just for demonstrating the issue, and doesn't make much sense otherwise. Regarding using a concurrent collection, I have considered it but this particular collection must be accessed with snapshot semantics. So I ended up using an [`ImmutableArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray). Here is the actual code in the finally block: `lock (_locker) _subscribers = _subscribers.Remove(subscriber);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would not claim that I fully understand the issue and how to fix it(and whose fault is it) but that's what I found:

First of all the finally block is translated to next IL:

```
  IL_017c: ldarg.0      // this
  IL_017d: ldfld        bool TestAsyncEnum.Program/'<GetStream>d__1'::'<>w__disposeMode'
  IL_0182: brfalse.s    IL_0186
  IL_0184: br.s         IL_0199
  IL_0186: ldarg.0      // this
  IL_0187: ldnull
  IL_0188: stfld        object TestAsyncEnum.Program/'<GetStream>d__1'::'<>s__2'

  // [37 17 - 37 58]
  IL_018d: ldstr        "Finally after lock"
  IL_0192: call         void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0197: nop

  // [38 13 - 38 14]
  IL_0198: nop

  IL_0199: endfinally
} // end of finally
```

As you can see the compiler generated code has next branching `IL_017d: ldfld bool TestAsyncEnum.Program/'<GetStream>d__1'::'<>w__disposeMode'` which will run the code after `lock` statement only if the generated enumerator is not in the disposeMode.

`System.Linq.Async` has two operators which internally use [`AsyncEnumerablePartition`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/AsyncEnumerablePartition.cs) - `Skip` and `Take`. Difference is that when `Take` finishes it does not run underlying enumerator to completion, and `Skip` does (I have elaborated here a little bit, cause have not looked in the underlying implementation), so when the disposal code is triggered for `Take` case the `disposeMode` is set to true and that part of code is not run.

Here is class (based on what's happening in the nuget) to repro issue:

```
public class MyAsyncIterator<T> : IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IAsyncEnumerable<T> _source;
    private IAsyncEnumerator<T>? _enumerator;
     T _current = default!;
    public T Current => _current;

    public MyAsyncIterator(IAsyncEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }

    public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken()) => this;

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (_enumerator != null)
        {
            await _enumerator.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            _enumerator = null;
        }
    }

    private int _taken;
    public async ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync()
    {
        _enumerator ??= _source.GetAsyncEnumerator();

        if (_taken < 1 && await _enumerator!.MoveNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            _taken++; // COMMENTING IT OUT MAKES IT WORK
            _current = _enumerator.Current;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And usage in your code `await foreach (var item in new MyAsyncIterator<int>(GetStream()))`

I would say that this is some edge case compiler issue, cause it seems to handle strangely all code after finally blocks, for example if your add `Console.WriteLine("After global finally");` to the end of `GetStream` it will not be printed also in case if the iterator has not "completed". Your workaround works cause the `WriteLine` is in finally block.

Submitted issue on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35779), will see what dotnet team will say.

Comment: Thanks Stron for the answer. Very interesting analysis and observations! Also thanks for [submiting](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35779) the issue to GitHub (I am too lazy to do it myself!).

Comment: NP, it was fun and educational for me =)